# Javascript onclick function works in everything except FF and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have written a simple quiz in javascript and it works fine in my browser of choice, but when I tested it in IE and FF the buttons don't work.  I get a "ReferenceError: Option1button() is not defined"

even in this little bit of code I get the same error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html><head><title></title></head>
    <body onload="loadPlayer();">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Option1button(){
                document.getElementById("op1").style.display = 'none';
            }
            function loadPlayer() {
                document.write("<div id=\"op1\"><button onclick='Option1button()'>choose</button> OPTIONS <br></div>");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You CANNOT use `document.write` anywhere except code that runs immediately.

If you are trying to defer it so that the button doesn't appear until the function is defined, just do this:

```
<body>
<script>function Option1Button() {...}</script>
<div id="op1">...</div>
```

Since scripts block the page from loading, the button won't appear until the function is ready to be called.